# Difference between echo and print in the Korn shell

Tags: shell, text-processing, ksh

In Ksh, `echo hello world` and `print hello world` will return the same output (hello world). What is the difference between these text processing commands with respect to the Korn Shell?

I know how they work in BaSH, Cshell, and tcsh.

Comment: see also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo

Comment: I saw that when I googled this question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ### III.   SHELL PROGRAMMING QUESTIONS
>
> [...]
>    Q12. Why does [ksh] have print since echo already exists [and] is widely used?
>
> A12.   The behavior of echo varies from system to system.
>             The POSIX standard does not define the behavior of echo when
>             the first argument beings with a - or when any argument
>             contains a \ character.  This makes echo pretty useless for
>             use in portable scripts.

http://kornshell.com/doc/faq.html

Comment: Note that ksh's `print` predates the `printf` command.

Comment: So basically what you're saying is they're the same?

Comment: For the korn shell

Comment: and by that logic (no portability) isn't print useless too? :/ It's use with tcsh csh and bash is completely different than with ksh which more resembles PRINT in BASIC than UNIX imo.